# Modify Foreign Key Relationships in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints, cascade

I would like to see some example how to modify foreign key relationship in **TSQL** because it is missing here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175493.aspx

Actually I want to apply delete rule **Cascade**.

Should it be like?

```
ALTER TABLE Email MODIFY
   CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email  
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: What's the question?  Just set it in the same GUI you are showing us, and then instead of saving changes, hit the "script changes" button.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I need TSQL to setup cascade rule.

Comment: The do what I said above, use the Script changes button.

Comment: You have a DBA that allows cacade delete? It is generally a poor idea on a production database.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Well... If you are meaning "Script Table as..." menu then it does not help at all. Do you mean some another button to get script of constrains of the specific table?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found how I can do it

```
GO
ALTER TABLE EmailContact DROP
   CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email
GO
ALTER TABLE EmailContact ADD
   CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email  
       FOREIGN KEY (EmailId)
      REFERENCES Email (Id)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Note that this might mark the `FOREIGN KEY` as "untrusted" - you will need to also run `ALTER TABLE EmailContact CHECK CONSTRAINT FK_EmailContact_Email` after your script above to rectify that. See here: https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/foreign-key-trusted/